# Find running apps

Tags: applications, application-manager

I am using Android 5.1.1 in a Samsung J7.
I want to know which apps are running.
I found at least two ways of checking that:

1. Settings -> Applications -> Application manager -> RUNNING
2. Trepn Profiler

There are some apps that show up in the list of any of the two methods. But some others show in only one of the two. For instance, Google Maps shows in Trepn Profiler, but not in the other.

**What is the explanation for this?**

Comment: Possibly Trepn is listing apps that are drawing power but not "running",  whereas OS is reporting those that are actually running?

Comment: @beeshyams - How would an app drain power without running, at least for a while?

Comment: Not sure, but for instance streaming ads could be a background activity possibly without app being active

Comment: @beeshyams - I do not know the technical difference between *application*, *service*, *activity*, and *other objects* in Android, so I cannot make too much sense of the comment. Trying to follow up, in your example, if there is an object (*activity*) behind something that uses up battery (streaming ads), without an associated *app*, I guess there is no *app* to be included in any of the two lists above, which give lists of apps running.

Comment: Let us wait for wise heads to clarify. I am also interested to know so upvoted your question